# r shiny sqlquery - populating checkbox from sql query results

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc

I need help in populating R shiny checkboxes with results from SQL query please.

Here is the full code and a specific description of the problem below that:

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server="" ;database="";trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select name from analysis order by name asc')

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", 
                       label = h3("Choose contracts"), 
                       choices = res$name,
                       selected = NULL),
    actionButton("action", label = "Create Portfolio EP")
    )

))

library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$action>0 & input$action<=2){
      valores<-renderText({
        input$checkGroup
      })
      data<-unlist(strsplit(valores(), split=" "))
      print(data)
    }
  })
})
```

The trouble is the checkboxes return this:

```
1
2
```

and the sql results in sql are this:

```
   name
1  a
2  b
```

so it looks like the results need to be formatted for R to capture correctly.

Any ideas, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for checkboxGroupInput, it says this for the `choices` argument

> List of values to show checkboxes for. If elements of the list are
>   named then that name rather than the value is displayed to the user.

So all you need to do is to convert the sql results to an unnamed structure, or manually set the names to NULL.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I tried this: 'choices = c("Acuity" = res[1,1]' and it returns "Acuity" instead of "1". However the issue is that the list may change and I have to automate it somehow. I'm not sure how to convert the sql results to an unnamed structure..?

Comment: I made this change:- rownames(res) <- res$name and choices = rownames(res) .. not a real solution, but it works. thank you.

Comment: I think you can just use `as.vector(res$name)`

Comment: thanks a lot!! may i please ask one further question? now i would like to display res$name on the interface but have the value stored as res$ID when it is clicked. i have tried everything now. i can't figure out the syntax. any ideas please? @warmoverflow

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to do. `res$name` is a column in your data, so `res$ID` would be another column. When you say "have the value stored as res$ID", do you mean you want to store the checked values into `res$ID`? This may not be possible because `checkboxGroupInput` only returns the checked values, so it may be shorter than the original column.

Comment: hi, table "res" now has 2 columns (sorry for the confusion): res$NAME and res$ID (each name has  a unique ID). i want to display res$NAME on the interface but i would like to be able to retrieve res$ID later if the corresponding name is clicked on the interface (i want to pass the ID into a sql query in the server). thanks in advance. please feel free to answer question if it is clear and i will accept. cheers. @warmoverflow

Comment: It would be `res$ID[res$name %in% input$checkGroup]` (I haven't tested this but the idea should be correct, basically you find the IDs corresponding to the names that matches the checked values)